# What debug info gets added by gcc?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc

I am building a program for an embedded system running OpenWRT using autotools within eclipse. I have it all set up for debugging and this works. If I send the compiled executable to someone will it be as efficient as one not compiled for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficency of the generated executable (for the same given source code) depends upon the compiler and the optimization flags.

If you compile your code with only `gcc -g` and *without* any optimization flags, it is much slower than if you compile it with optimization flags (e.g. `gcc -O2`).

You may mix both `-O2` and `-g` if you want. Adding the `-g` won't slow down the executable (but will add some debug info). The `gdb` debugger will probably display some weird behavior when debugging such an executable (because optimization is inlining, reordering instructions, etc...)

You might find that compiling with `gcc -O1 -g` is an appropriate compromise. And recent GCC (i.e. 4.8) has even added a `-Og` option (optimize for debugging) i.e. compile with `gcc -Og -g`.

Comment: Good point. It won't be optimal 'cause I turn optimisations off for debugging. Thank you.